# Name with gear icon in Chrome network requests table

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, web-worker

[image]

[image]

(30119999.xml in pic1, has a gear mark pre name)

I set this request in Web Worker, response data is ok and I terminated it in onmessage callback

but why the request always in pending and can't preview, please help.

pseudocode:

```
const workerBlob = new Blob([`onmessage = function (event) {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.addEventListener('load', function () {
        postMessage(xhr.response);
    });
    xhr.open('GET', event.data.url, true);
    xhr.send();
}`], { type: 'application/javascript' });
const workerURL = URL.createObjectURL(workerBlob);
const worker = new Worker(workerUrl);
worker.postMessage({url});
worker.onmessage = (message) => {
    // do something
    worker.terminate();
};
```

Comment: Having the same issue with Chrome 65.0.3325.162 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 28):

According to [Debugging Service Workers](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/debugging-service-workers/#3) :

> The gear icon signifies that these requests came from the Service
>   Worker itself. Specifically, these are the requests being made by the
>   Service Worker's install handler to populate the offline cache.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not terminating your worker too fast. You should terminate the Worker when the [loadend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/loadend) event has fired.