# What a gear icon means in Google Chrome's DevTools' Network Tab?

Tags: google-chrome, networking, devtools

Today I was inspecting the network of a website, and I saw a gear icon besides a network call:

[image]

I googled around and couldn't find anything. What does it mean?

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48336926/name-with-gear-icon-in-chrome-network-requests-table/54268752

Comment: **See Also** [Name with gear icon in Chrome network requests table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48336926/1366033)

Answer (score 6):

The Gear icon in the requests in means the request came from service worker. it generally fetches the same assets for offline cache.

You can refer to this [Service worker docs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/debugging-service-workers/#3) which says

> The gear icon signifies that these requests came from the Service Worker itself. Specifically, these are the requests being made by the Service Worker's install handler to populate the offline cache.